# AWS CloudFormation: "User doesn't have permission to call ssm:GetParameters"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

The documentation says: "If you don't specify a value, [...] CloudFormation uses a temporary session that's generated from your user credentials."
So I have the ssm:GetParameters permission. Proof:

```
$ aws ssm get-parameters --name /dev/ec2/instanceType                                                                                                {
    "Parameters": [
        {
            "Name": "/dev/ec2/instanceType",
            "Type": "String",
            "Value": "t8.pico",
            "Version": 1,
            "LastModifiedDate": "2023-09-27T17:22:30.797000+01:00",
            "ARN": "arn:aws:ssm:eu-central-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:parameter/dev/ec2/instanceType",
            "DataType": "text"
        }
    ],
    "InvalidParameters": []
}
```

But that is not enough:

```
$ aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name s2 --template-body=file://sample_cloud_formation_template.yaml

An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: AccessDenied. User doesn't have permission to call ssm:GetParameters
```

Now one can specify a role to run the command with, so I tried that as well, created a role with following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now again:

```
$ aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name s2 --template-body=file://sample_cloud_formation_template.yaml --role-arn arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/aaa-role-with-aaa-cloud-form-with-ssm-get-parameters

An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: AccessDenied. User doesn't have permission to call ssm:GetParameters
```

What am I missing here?

I tried both

- create-stack with my user (who as admin rights)
- create-stack with a role that has ssm:getParameters

I always get this annoying "User doesn't have permission to call ssm:GetParameters".

Additionnally,

$ aws sts get-caller-identity
{
"UserId": "AIDAW................",
"Account": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
"Arn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:user/sam"
}

returns the expected user.

Comment: "So I have the ssm:GetParameters permission. Proof: `$ aws ssm get-parameter ...`" [`GetParameter` and `GetParameters` are different calls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_awssystemsmanager.html), so that proves nothing.  Do it again with `get-parameters` call.     I'd generally debug this by comparing the user / role session information in the error with `aws sts get-caller-identity` to make sure you're actually who you think you are - very often folks can end up under the wrong profile.  For us to help you verify you'd have to not remove those details

Comment: Edited with "getParameters" instead of "getParameter" and the result of "sts get-caller-identity". How do you get the "user/role session information in the error" ?

Comment: Is this your personal account? Are there any SCPs in place?

Comment: There is one SCP, "arn:aws:organizations::aws:policy/service_control_policy/p-FullAWSAccess". Yes, it is my personal account.

Comment: @smarquis what are the contents of the SCP?

Comment: I expected " User XXX doesn't have permission to call ssm:GetParameters" to have a user ARN in it that you had removed for privacy, but that isn't necessarily the case.  I do see your user identity has a funny prefix `"UserId": "AIDAW................"` that's not an IAM user credential  `(AIKA...)` or a session token from a user credential (`ASIA...`) or an assumed role (`AROA...` )  but it corresponds to an IAM user.